# How do I use zxing.net in my visual C# form

Tags: c#, webcam, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have never done anything like this before and slowly trying to learn C# for personal use.

I am trying to create a program that reads a barcode from a webcam and outputs the barcode's number. I was recommended to use `zxing.Net` but i have no idea where to start.

1. How do i get input from my webcam and output to the C# windows form.
2. How do i use `zxing.Net` to convert the barcode into a number combination.
3. How do i output this to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a demo WindowsForms application, which show encoding and decoding from a webcam in the source-code on codeplex:

http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Clients/WindowsFormsDemo/Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but with a little research I can suggest this:

1. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C) article - it has a working example of how to get a stream from a USB camera. It's not simple, but it is worth trying :)
2. On this page: http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ scroll to the Usage Example. Over there I can see that it accepts a bitmap and then returns a result or a null if it can't recognize the barcode. So, all you need to do from #1 is to convert the stream to a bitmap object and pass it to zxing barcode reader.
3. zxing.NET returns the decoded number in plain text, so you can output it to the screen on any way you want?

Any reason not to use a barcode reader device?

Comment: Hey, which article should i check? and as i already own a webcam but not a barcode reader. Thanks for the response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do visit this article, to download a c# qr decoding working code sample using zxing library:
http://www.itechflare.com/main/blog/c-program-for-2d-barcode-decoding/

regards

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.